# PowerShell and Outlook - Inconsistent

Tags: powershell, automation, outlook, outlook-2007

I have a problem with the following PowerShelll script:

```
$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$mail.To = "aaa@gmail.com"
$mail.Subject = "PowerShell Test 1"
$mail.Body = "Body..."
$mail.HTMLBody = "This is test!"   
$mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Test.txt")    
$mail.save()

$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$mail.To = "aaa@gmail.com"
$mail.Subject = "PowerShell Test 2"
$mail.Body = "Body..."
$mail.HTMLBody = "This is test!"   
$mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Test.txt")    
$mail.save()
```

When Outlook IS ALREADY STARTED, script works fine - as expected, I get two emails in Drafts folder.

When Outlook IS NOT STARTED, Outlook first asks user for permissions but at the end I get ONLY SECOND email in Drafts, FIRST EMAIL is missing.

Has anyone encountered this problem, any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping this in a try/catch block?  @Ocaso It's probably $outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; but would be good if the OP would confirm.

Comment: I have no problem. I see both drafts even when Outlook is closed.

Comment: On my machine the first is not missing, but in INBOX-folder (Win 7/64, Outlook 2007)

Comment: I confirm that $outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;

Comment: @nimizen - I did not wrapped in try catch - in the output window everything looks fine, no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as Ocaso where the first email was being sent to the inbox and the second was sent to drafts.  I fixed this problem by setting up a session for outlook:

```
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
$session = $outlook.Session
$session.Logon()
```

The session basically sets up a time period of when an application, outlook in this case, can take in or setup data.  By calling session.Logon(), we're instantiating a session or time period of when outlook can save data/email.  The below article does a better job of explaining sessions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Thanks